# How can I get a color that from user input and convert it to RGB values that I can use in my main code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a code that receives 3 colors from a user and return an array of 9 values, RGB values for every color, I found this code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser


def choose_color():
    color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Choose color")
    print(color_code[0][0], color_code[0][1], color_code[0][2])


root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Select color", command=choose_color)
button.pack()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.mainloop()
```

but it only prints the values so I can't do calculations with them.

Comment: Just... use the `color_code` value instead of printing it? If you are a beginner, copying some code that you don't understand will not make things easier. Better read tutorials or sth like that, than starting with some rather complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can `return` but it won't work here because you are not the one who directly calls the callback. It is the event loop that listens and calls it back.

So we will need to do some kind of global manipulating. Since you have 3 values needed, 3 separate globals won't be so good. Instead, we had better use a container. This can be a `dict` or a `namedtuple`, for example.

With a `dict`:

```
import tkinter as tk

USER_RGB_DICT = {}


def choose_color():
    color_code = tk.colorchooser.askcolor(title="Choose color")
    # we use unpacking here
    r, g, b = color_code[0]

    # store the choosings in the dict
    USER_RGB_DICT["R"] = r
    USER_RGB_DICT["G"] = g
    USER_RGB_DICT["B"] = b

    # example: another button for calculations is now available
    calc_button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate with color", command=calculations_rgb)
    calc_button.pack()


def calculations_rgb():
    # since dicts preserve insertion order, we can do this
    r, g, b = USER_RGB_DICT.values()

    # some calculations
    if b > 200 and 50 > g and 50 > r:
        print("user really likes blue")


# initialize root
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

# place a button
button = tk.Button(root, text="Select color", command=choose_color)
button.pack()

# fire the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

In the `calculations_rgb` function above, you have the `r`, `g`, `b` values the user chose, and you can do things with them.

Note: `from tkinter import *` is not good because it imports many things! Something like `E` is even imported! That can clash with your variables, function names etc. It is better if `from ... import *` is avoided here. Instead, one can use `import tkinter as tk` and refer to things over `tk`.